# eclipse error XML structures have to start and finish with the same entity

Tags: xml

right am crabbing out because i have been trying to sort this error out for days and its stopping me from learning android development i always get this error (in the title ) but i cant find any mistakes in my coding can anyone help me sort this thing out before i teach my laptop how to fly thankyou

```
</LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="your total is 0"
android:textSize="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
></TextView>
<Button
android:layout_width="250dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add one"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/bSub"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="subtract one"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
</LinearLayout>  **this is where the error line is and am new to this stuff so sorry if its somthing simple **
```

Comment: i also have this when i try to run it on a pop-up window An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the '/' from the starting of the linear layout tag in the xml..